# Can't find Rendered Component via <MemoryRouter /> - react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jsdom

I can't find my rendered DashBoard component.  I'm using enzyme's mount().

I get an instance of  back after mounted so not sure how I can find() my component as it doesn't recognize find() on a  wrapper

**jsdom.js**

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom')
const { JSDOM } = jsdom

    global.window = new JSDOM(`<!doctype html><html><body id='root'></body></html>`).window
    global.document = window.document
```

**test**

```
require('../jsdom')

describe('Protected Route', () => {
  let store, app, index, responseBody

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = initStore()

    const App = ({store}) => (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Layout>
          <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute component={DashboardContainer} path='/dashboard'/>
          </Switch>
        </Layout>
      </Provider>)

    app = mount(<MemoryRouter><App store={store} /></MemoryRouter>)
  })

  it.only('renders requested route if authenticated', () => {
    const dashboard = app.find(DashboardContainer)
    expect(dashboard).to.exist
  })
})
```

the problem is app is referring to the  instance.  It tried app.dive() but it doesn't recognize dive().  And app.find() give `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`
[image]